# yeoman: Using yo webapp followed by adding backbone and backbone.layoutmanager to the mix

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, yeoman, bower

I successfully installed a webapp using the yeoman webapp generator plugin.

I wanted to add backbone and backbone.layoutmanager to the mix.

But I get errors such as https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3275 when I attempted to run `npm install && bower install`.

This is my current main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../components/jquery/jquery',
        backbone: '../../node_modules/backbone/backbone',
        underscore: "../components/underscore/underscore",
        layoutmanager: "../../node_modules/backbone.layoutmanager/backbone.layoutmanager",
        bootstrap: 'vendor/bootstrap'
    },
    shim: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        layoutmanager: {
            deps: ["backbone"],
            exports: "Backbone.Layout"
        }
    },

});

require(['app', 'jquery', 'bootstrap'], function (app, $) {
    'use strict';
    // use app here
    console.log(app);
    console.log('Running jQuery %s', $().jquery);
});
```

My current component.json

```
{
  "name": "learnbackbonelayoutmanager",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "sass-bootstrap": "~2.3.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.4",
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2",
    "jquery": "~1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

My current package.json

```
{
  "name": "learnbackbonelayoutmanager",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.1.2",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.1.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "0.1.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "0.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "0.1.2",
    "grunt-contrib-livereload": "0.1.1",
    "grunt-bower-hooks": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~0.1.9",
    "grunt-regarde": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-requirejs": "~0.3.2",
    "grunt-mocha": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
    "matchdep": "~0.1.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  }
}
```

**How do I setup a webapp default as defined by `yo webapp` and still add in Backbone and Backbone.LayoutManager to it?**

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the question correctly. Do you want to build your own generator that works like `generator-webapp`, but also adds those two modules to it?

Comment: I do not want to build a generator at this time. I just want to setup a simple website as specified by the `yo webapp` and then add in two more modules, namely: backbone, and backbone layout manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have installed backbone and layoutmanager via `npm`. If you want to use these as frontend components, you should install them via `bower`:

```
bower install --save backbone layoutmanager
```

After that, adjust the paths in your `main.js` like this:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../components/jquery/jquery',
        backbone: '../../components/backbone/backbone',
        underscore: '../components/underscore/underscore',
        layoutmanager: '../components/backbone.layoutmanager/backbone.layoutmanager',
        bootstrap: 'vendor/bootstrap'
    },
    shim: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        layoutmanager: {
            deps: ['backbone'],
            exports: 'Backbone.Layout'
        }
    },

});

require(['app', 'jquery', 'bootstrap'], function (app, $) {
    'use strict';
    // use app here
    console.log(app);
    console.log('Running jQuery %s', $().jquery);
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between installing via npm and via bower? Sounds like npm is for server-side JS and bower is for frontend JS?

Comment: Exactly. Bower is for browser packages.